# Express nodejs socket.io with cordova

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to implement `socket.io` on my server. This server is an API (express nodejs).

The server side is simple, but for the client side I'm using `phonegap/cordova`.

I **don't** use a phone to test what I do, I use my browser (chrome).

Si this the server side :

```
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  console.log(socket);

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('socket disconnected');
    });

  io.emit('text', 'wow. such event. very real time.');

});
```

for now, this is simple,

But for the **client side** I am completely confuse (cordova phonegap),

This is what I have :

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.3.js"></script>


<script>

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

    socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log('send')
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
    });
</script>
```

Nothing appears but errors like

> GET http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1462638049681-3 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

and **nothing** on my server

any ideas to help me ? thanks :)

Comment: On which port, the server is listening for connection ?

Comment: I don't know, all you can see from the server is in the code you can see

Comment: Yes, port is the issue, check my answer. It should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is not listening on port `8080`. That's why when you try to connect from browser to  `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');`, it shows `'Connection Refused'`.

This edit would work for you.

```
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using     express
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  console.log(socket);
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('socket disconnected');
  });
  io.emit('text', 'wow. such event. very real time.');
});

//Now server would listen on port 8080 for new connection
http.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8080');
});
```

Comment: that was simply it ! thans :)